# How Many Ways to Choose Dance Partners if Choosing Both Men and Women?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I was working through supplementary exercises in Grimaldi, and I came across a question about dance partners--it asked how to choose a clean-up team of 8 from a group of 12 men, and then asked how many different ways to pair up 8 women from those 12 men.  The answer was simple enough: find the number of permutations of size 8 from a set of 12 men (i.e., $\frac{12!}{4!})$.  But that got me wondering, if we want to choose *both* the men and the women from a set of 12 each, how does the answer change?  Since I'm completely new to self-studying math, I thought I'd pose the question to see if my approach to answering the question is valid (I thought it might still have something to do with permutations, but I wasn't sure).

So let's say there are 12 men and 12 women at a dance.  How many ways are there to pair off 8 men and 8 women as dance partners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{12}8$ ways to choose the men, and $\binom{12}8$ ways to choose the women.  Once the people have been chosen there are $8!$ ways to pair them off.  (Stand the women in a line.  There are $8!$ ways to shuffle the men, then we pair the first man with the first woman, the second man with the second woman, and so on.)

The answer is $$\binom{12}{8}^2\cdot8!=9,879,408,000
$$

Answer (score 3):

Here's my guess.  First we choose 8 men from the 12 total men, which is $\binom{12}{8}$.  Then, once we have the 8 men chosen, we find the permutations of 8 women from the set of 12, which is $\frac{12!}{(12-8)!} = \frac{12!}{4!}$.  The total number of ways should therefore be:

$$
\binom{12}{8} \times \frac{12!}{4!}
$$

Comment: Hint: Can you simplify to choose 2 pairs to form partners from 3 pairs and start from there ?

Comment: Well if I wanted to choose 2 pairs from 3 men and 3 women, that would be 18 different combinations, right?  (I wrote them out and that's what I got.)  And my method would give $\binom{3}{2} \times \frac{3!}{1!} = 18$, so that seems to be correct.  I could be missing something, though.

Comment: Note that $\binom{12}{8}=\frac{12!}{8!4!}$ so  $\binom{12}{8}\frac{12!}{4!}= \binom{12}{8}^28!$ which also has a combinatorial explanation - choose all the dancers first and then count the ways to pair them.

Comment: You are right - if you  need to line them up .If not, just $\binom{3}{2} \times \binom{3}{2}=9$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us simplify the question.  Imagine you have to choose 2 pairs from 3 pairs of men  and woman (M1-M3,W1-W3) to form partners.

Step 1:
Chose 2 from  3 men,  $\binom{3}{2}$ =3 choices.

Step 2:
Chose 2 from  3 women, $\binom{3}{2}$ =3 choices.

Step 3:
Then to pair them $\to$

```
If no need  to line them up, 3x3 =  9

If need line them up, 3x3x2! =18
```

Now, we can answer the  original question.